# How to convert date format May 25 1921 12:00AM to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with dob field as varchar datatype, i performed dateadd function on few record. Now i have few records with 
May 25 1921 12:00AM format and some with yyyy-mm-dd format.

How do i set all records with same dateformat in the tableof varchar datatype?

Thanks

Comment: You should _not_ be storing date/time information in a `varchar` column, this is asking for trouble down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```
  select convert(varchar(10), cast('May 25 1921 12:00AM' as date),120)
```

to Update :

```
   update TableName set dob=convert(varchar(10),cast(dob as datetime),120)
   from TableName
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do an update:

```
update your_table set dob=convert(varchar(25),cast(dob as datetime),120)
```

This will be the Temporary solution, I strongly recommend you to use `datetime` type for the datetime values. Otherwise, you will face many issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Below code for convert varchar to date :

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'May 25 1921 12:00AM',103)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table MyTable
 add NewDate Date;

update MyTable
set NewDate = cast(Olddate as date);
```